# Visual Basic: What is the difference between controls.remove(object) and object.hide()?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

What is the difference between controls.remove(object) and object.hide()?
Giving examples are welcome.

Comment: Is this for WinForms applications or ASP.NET?

Comment: WinForms applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls.Remove(object) is a very dangerous method and is used wrong 99% of the time.  Programmers think it gets rid of the control but it does not, only object.Dispose() does that.  A removed control continues to live on the hidden "parking window".  The intent is to make it easy to move a control from one parent to another without destroying and re-creating the native window.  A good example is hard to come by, a minor use case is to hide a TabPage with the intent to restore it again later.  That still has to be done very carefully, you have to keep track of the removed pages and dispose them yourself when the form is closed.  Controls.Clear() is very dangerous for the same reason.

There's nothing wrong with Hide().